# asURLRequest Alamofire try error

Tags: url, swift3, alamofire

In Swift 3.0, I have the following throws function used to produce a URLRequest.

```
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

        let result: (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = try {
            switch self {
            case .PopularPhotos (let userID, let accessToken):
                let params = try ["access_token": accessToken]
                let pathString = try "/v1/users/" + userID + "/media/recent"
                return try (pathString, params as [String : AnyObject]?)

            case .requestOauthCode:
                let pathString = try "/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + Router.clientID + "&redirect_uri=" + Router.redirectURI + "&response_type=code"
                return try (pathString, nil)

            default: break

            }
        }()
```

However, when I go to call the function:

```
let request = Instagram.Router.requestOauthCode.asURLRequest()
```

I get the following error: "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.

I have looked at several tutorials into error handling and throwing functions in Swift 3.0 and I can't figure out how handle errors here.

The complete class code is below:

```
struct Instagram {

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "https://api.instagram.com"
    static let clientID = "cf97d864faf14f90a1557c4b972c990e"
    static let redirectURI = "http://www.example.com/"
    static let clientSecret = "7f1ce6147f924afc92dea31f5354ca06"

    case PopularPhotos(String, String)
    case requestOauthCode

    static func requestAccessTokenURLStringAndParms(code: String) -> (URLString: String, params: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let params = ["client_id": Router.clientID, "client_secret": Router.clientSecret, "grant_type": "authorization_code", "redirect_uri": Router.redirectURI, "code": code]
        let pathString = "/oauth/access_token"
        let urlString = Instagram.Router.baseURLString + pathString
        return try (urlString, params as [String : AnyObject])
    }
    // MARK: URLRequestConvertible

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {

        let result: (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) = try {
            switch self {
            case .PopularPhotos (let userID, let accessToken):
                let params = try ["access_token": accessToken]
                let pathString = try "/v1/users/" + userID + "/media/recent"
                return try (pathString, params as [String : AnyObject]?)

            case .requestOauthCode:
                let pathString = try "/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" + Router.clientID + "&redirect_uri=" + Router.redirectURI + "&response_type=code"
                return try (pathString, nil)

            default: break

            }
        }()


        let baseURL = try Router.baseURLString.asURL()
        let urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: baseURL.appendingPathComponent(result.path))
        return try Alamofire.URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: result.parameters)




    }

}
```

}

Comment: Does anyone know to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your function call inside a `do-catch` block and mark it with `try`. Something like this

```
do {    
    let request = try Instagram.Router.requestOauthCode.asURLRequest()

    // Continue with normal flow here.
} catch {
    // Handle error here.
}
```

Comment: In the line after that i have smthg like:
self.webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
it says now... amibiguous reference to member request(_:method:parameters:encoding:headers)